# Obtener contexto afuera de MainActivity

Tags: android, activity

Necesito pasar el contexto al siguiente método

```
public class MiBaseDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int VERSION_BASEDATOS = 1;

    // Nombre de nuestro archivo de base de datos
    private static final String NOMBRE_BASEDATOS = "eventosUTN.db";

    // Sentencia SQL para la creación de una tabla
    private static final String TABLA_EVENTOS_UTN = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eventosUTN" +
            "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, titulo TEXT, fecha TEXT, tipo_evento TEXT, dirigido_a TEXT, area TEXT, descripcion TEXT)";


    // CONSTRUCTOR de la clase
    public MiBaseDatos(Context context) {
        super(context, NOMBRE_BASEDATOS, null, VERSION_BASEDATOS);
    }
..... 
 }
```

Como se observa el constructor necesita el contexto pero dicha clase es instanciada en:

```
  class ClienteTCP extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
  ....
  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String value){
            if (!value.isEmpty()){
                MiBaseDatos db = new MiBaseDatos(getApplicationContext());
                String mensaje=value.substring(8);
                String [] datos= mensaje.split(";¬");
                respuesta.setText(mensaje);
         ......
          }
 ......
  }
```

Se ve como en protected void onPostExecute(String value) es llamada la clase MiBaseDatos. No hay problemas si está definida la case ClienteTCP en MainActivity pero si defino la clase ClienteTCP en otro archivo afuera de MainActivity, no puedo obtener el contexto de la clase. ¿cómo puedo hacerlo? ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas el contexto ahí?

Comment: Porque SQLiteOpenHelper lo requiere para abrir/crear base de datos SQlite

Comment: Ya pero generalmente eso se hace desde una Activity ¿por qué no creas desde la Activity una instancia de la clase para consultar la base de datos?

Comment: Pero no hay forma de hacer referencia al contexto? Porque todas las clases son llamadas (instanciadas) desde MainActivity

Comment: Tengo que pasar el contexto porque sino no es posible utilizar la clase SQliteOpenHelper, debido a que es necesario el contexto para los directorios.

Comment: Puedes pedir el contexto en la clase ClienteTCP, cuyo constructor es ClienteTCP(Context context) {}.  Con tiempo, prueba a inyectar dependencias de forma manual o con algún inyector como Dagger 2 ya que funciona con Java.

Comment: Te tira algun error en especifico? Por favor danos mas datos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres obtener el contexto de `ClienteTCP` desde `MiBaseDatos` tenes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
//Variable para almacenar el contexto
private Context context;

// CONSTRUCTOR de la clase
    public MiBaseDatos(Context context) {
        super(context, NOMBRE_BASEDATOS, null, VERSION_BASEDATOS);

        //Asignas el contexto pasado a la variable
        this.context=context;
    }
```

Y luego con `context` ya podes usar el contexto que le pases por contructor en toda la clase.

Para enviar el contexto desde el constructor en `ClienteTCP` a `MiBaseDatos` desde el metodo onPostExecute() simplemente deberia funcionar con `getApplicationContext()`, pero te recomiendo que llames a `getApplicationContext()` desde el "cuerpo" de la clase y almacenes el contexto en una variable para luego pasarsela al metodo.

Algo asi como:

```
...
MiBaseDatos db = new MiBaseDatos(contexto);
...
```